# Any issues with Rails 3.2+ on Ubuntu 12.04. Also, 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-12.04

Setting up a new Linode server, and while I've had good luck with 10.04 LTS for a while now, I have decided to take the plunge into the latest and greatest.

Anyone have any issues with 12.04 LTS? Also, I was going to go with 32 bit, but the default download is 64 bit, so I am reconsidering. Anyone have any opinions, warnings regarding using 64 bit? I know Linode says it recommends 32 distros in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with 12.04 LTS 64-bit. No issues. Successfully running Rails 3.2 with SQL Server and NGINX.